# Why are some dentist-recommended products not accepted by the ADA?

Tags: dentistry, hygiene

I've wondered this for a long time now, and I think ACT Restoring Mouthwash is a good example of this: If you look at the front label it says "#1 Dentist Recommended Fluoride Brand" on it, and the other day my dentist recommended it to me as well. However the label does not have the "ADA-accepted" seal of approval on it.

Until my dentist recommended this to me, I've always avoided dental products (e.g. toothpaste, mouthwash) that haven't been accepted by the ADA (American Dental Association). To me it seems that if a product comes highly recommended by dentists then it's obvious that it is also accepted by the ADA. However this is not always the case.

What are the criteria used by the ADA in deciding whether to accept a product?

Comment: I think that if some other references were added this would be a viable question.